# C++: how to transfer files to netcat listener?

Tags: c++, file-transfer, irc

I'm working on an IRC server using c++, and I want to add files transfer to my server, but I don't know how to create the file in the user's host. I can read the file and send the bytes to netcat, but netcat will receive bytes only. How do I make netcat create a new file in the user's machine?

```
void    _fileTransfer(char *filepath, int senderFd)
{
    FILE*    fd = fopen(filepath, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL)
        return ;
    char    buffer[256];
    int    bytes_read;
    int    sock = clientfd;
    while (!feof(fd)) {
        if ((bytes_read = fread(&buffer, 1, 255, fd)) > 0)
            send(sock, buffer, bytes_read, 0);
        else
            break;
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: netcat is not an irc client. The way to tell an irc client to create a file is specified in the irc specs. Read them, use them.

Comment: I read them but I didn't see the part where the file transfer is explained?

Comment: You can read up on it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-to-client_protocol. There is no RFC for it.